# Using string/array to buid query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I want to create a procedure which selects items from database where id is not in specified collection.

The collection is passed as text parameter (here it is declared to show the problem):

```
DECLARE @IDs nvarchar(500);
SET @IDS = '2499043,2499042,2499041,2499040,2499039,2499038,2499037'
```

I found the solution that works and displays result:

```
Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
Select @ProductsSQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Items] WHERE (ID not in (' + @IDs + '))'
exec sp_executesql @ProductsSQL
```

The problem is that would like to process (make next select from this result) and return them.

How can I get results from 'sp_executesql'?

Or can anyone suggest other solution - the form of parameter can change (string was the best in my opinion but as you can see I cannot solve the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store result of the Query into `temptable` and use that 'temptable' for processing.

You can try this code :

```
Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
Select @ProductsSQL = 'SELECT * into [tempdb].[dbo].[temptable] FROM [Items] WHERE (ID not in (' + @IDs + '))'
exec sp_executesql @ProductsSQL

SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[temptable]

DROP TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[temptable]
```